# Reading a text file using Spark and inserting the value on spark sql

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

lines = sc.textFile("s3://test_bucket/txt/testing_consol.txt")

llist = lines.collect()

for lines in llist:
        final_query = spark.sql("""{0}
        """.format(lines))
```

This is what inside the txt file:

```
select * from test_table 
where id=1
```

I'm having the error message:

> "\nmismatched input 'where' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD',
>   'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE',
>   'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET',
>   'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR',
>   'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE',
>   'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 1,
>   pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nwhere id=1\n^^^\n"

The spark sql works if I change the content of the txt file into a single line:

```
select * from test_table where id=1
```

It seems like the spark sql could only recognize the first line and not the succeeding line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just merge the query lines it should work:

```
llist = ' '.join(lines.collect())
final_query = spark.sql(llist)
```

Comment: I'm having the error message: name 'sparkSession' is not defined.

Comment: I have tried to use spark.sql instead of sparkSession.sql and it is now working fine, it is like joining all the lines in a single line. so if this will be the case then we can't add comments to the script right because it will cause the sql to fail. I was able to run a more complex query but I need to remove the comments to do so. This works fine for now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to read the query, creating a rdd is not at a option.
You should pass the text file containing query to spark driver using --files parameter
then read the file using python open command and pass your query to spark sql.

To read small files just to pass query is not at all recommended using spark.